# How to use internal cloudera jars in oozie workflows

Tags: jar, cloudera, oozie, bigdata

When running various oozie actions I need some basic jars that are installed along side with cloudera(I know they exist in the cluster).

For example when running pig action i need a piggybank.jar and I want to use the internal one provided by cloudera and not add duplicate jar to my customer lib dir.

Question is How to use(reference) these internal jars in pig,bash scripts?

Comment: The PIG documentation states that you can start your script with sthg like `REGISTER /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/wtf/pig/duh/blahblah/pigshavewings.jar ;` so that the Java "classloader" dynamically adds that JAR to the CLASSPATH. Provided that you know the exact name of that JAR as installed on all DataNodes.

Comment: Yeach, but I want more generic solution, these cloudera could be in diffrent place, depends on cluster environment. I know that cloudera expose generic classpaths to directories with jars but i don't how to use them in script